# how to customize the terminal appearance from within the terminal

Tags: command-line, customization, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just got the Ubuntu bash terminal on windows and I really like being able to do linux stuff on windows, but I want to customize the terminal appearance. I know on actual Ubuntu you can customize the appearance of the terminal with the GUI, but what commands can you run to customize it from the LUI? A link to the documentation would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think that [Oliver Salzburg's](https://superuser.com/users/36744/oliver-salzburg) answer on Super User [pretty much covers it](https://superuser.com/a/1128329/576098):

> The problem is not specific to bash on Ubuntu for Windows, as the
>   terminal is still provided by `conhost.exe`.
>
> To change the colors, you can go into the **Defaults**:
>
> [image]
>
> And then you can click each individual color and change it to some
>   other color.
>
> [image]
>
> The process is somewhat confusing, because by clicking a color
>   rectangle, you're changing what is selected as the **Screen
>   Background**. So you first have to change that selection, adjust the
>   color and then change the selection back to your desired background
>   color.
>
> Overall, it is easier to just go with a different terminal or console
>   emulator altogether. I personally use
>   [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) now, which allows you to change
>   color schemes much easier.

---

[Guillermo González de Garibay](https://superuser.com/users/523981/guillermo-gonz%C3%A1lez-de-garibay) also has a [nice answer](https://superuser.com/a/1198648/576098) on Super User:

> This is also a nice and easy solution, from
>   https://medium.com/@iraklis/fixing-dark-blue-colors-on-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-c6b009f8b97c
>   :
>
> Append this to `.bashrc`:
>
> ```
> LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=1;35:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';
> export LS_COLORS
>
> PS1='\e[37;1m\u@\e[35m\W\e[0m\$ ' # this will change your prompt format
> ```
>
> And I found this useful too for vim's readability:
>
> ```
> echo "set background=dark" >> .vimrc
> ```